# trying to find asymptotic or approximate solutions to coupled diffusion-advection-decay equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, asymptotics, approximation

I am trying to solve a set of diffusion-advection equations with coupled decay (see unanswered [coupled diffusion-advection-decay equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4481820/coupled-diffusion-advection-decay-equations)). The equations are as follows:
\begin{align} 
 u_t - \alpha u_{xx} + c u_x +\lambda (u-v) = 0 \tag{1} 
\end{align}
\begin{align} 
 v_t - \alpha v_{xx} - c v_x +\lambda (v-u) = 0 \tag{2} 
\end{align}
on $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R_+$ with $\lambda \geq0$, $\alpha > 0$, $c>0$. The functions at $t = 0$ are
$~u(x,0) = \delta(x), ~x \in \mathbb R$ and $v(x,0) = -\delta(x), ~x \in \mathbb R$.

I'm interested in the steady state ($v_t = u_t = 0$). This can be solved analytically if $\lambda = 0$ (just two uncoupled diffusion-advection solutions).

Am I wrong to conclude that in steady state at large $x$ , $u = v$? The analytic solutions without $\lambda$ do not have $u = v$. What surprises me is that turning on $\lambda$ by even the smallest amount forces $u = v$. I've tried to tackle these numerically and I don't get $u=v$ but I think it's because of numerical accuracy.

I'm also interested in long-time dependence of the solutions. Numerically I find the power law behavior.

Comment: The steady state can be solved analytically for all $\lambda$. Add and subtract the two equations separately to get \begin{align}
-\alpha (u + v)_{xx} + c (u - v)_{x} &= 0 \\
-\alpha (u - v)_{xx} + c (u + v)_{x} + 2 \lambda (u - v) &= 0 \\
\end{align} Then define $A = u + v, B = u - v$. The first equation can be integrated to get $\alpha A_{x} = c B + K_{1}$. Substituting into the second equation gives you an ODE in $B$ to solve that should have exponential solutions with real argument and a particular solution that is constant. Then you can find $A$ and in turn find $u, v$.

Comment: @mattos I've done this and do find that $u = v$ at large $x$. Could I've predicted that by just looking at the original equations?  When $\lambda = 0$, I can't determine the relationship between $u$ and $v$ by using the boundary conditions $u'(\infty) = u'(\infty) = 0$. I know that for diffusion-advection (no decay), $u$ and $v$ will not be equal but I'm not seeing this. Perhaps I need to add a source term?

Comment: @mattos ok, I added a continuous point source at the origin. I get the standard solutions for diffusion-advection when $\lambda$ = 0 (finite $A$ and $B$ downstream). When I try for positive $\lambda$, $A$ is finite at $\infty$ but $B$ is zero. There is no way to take the solutions for finite $\lambda$ and get back diffusion-advection solutions by taking the limit of small $\lambda$. This seems wrong. Does this type of behavior have a name?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are doing. Unless I've made a mistake, if you solve the equations as I stated yesterday then you should find \begin{align} B&=D_{1}e^{\sqrt{\gamma_{1}} x}+D_{2} e^{- \sqrt{\gamma_{1}} x} - \gamma_{1}^{-1} \gamma_{2} \\ A &= \alpha^{-1} c (\gamma_{1}^{-1/2} D_{1} e^{\sqrt{\gamma_{1}} x} - \gamma_{2}^{-1/2} D_{2} e^{- \sqrt{\gamma_{1}} x} - \gamma_{1}^{-1} \gamma_{2} x) + K_{1} x + K_{2} \end{align} where $\gamma_{1} = \alpha^{-1} (\alpha^{-1} c^{2} + 2 \lambda), \gamma_{2} = c \alpha^{-2} K_{1}$. Then $A$ and $B$ are bounded at infinity provided $D_{1}, K_{1} = 0$.

Comment: @mattos Looks about the same as I have. It does show the crux of my question. $K_1$ needs to be zero. This forces $B$ to be 0 at large $x$. Now take your $A$ and $B$ at set $\lambda = 0$.  $B$ will of course still be $0$ at $\infty$.  However, if one sets $\lambda = 0$ from the beginning:  \begin{align} 
 - \alpha u_{xx} + c u_x  = 0 \tag{1} 
\end{align}
\begin{align} 
- \alpha v_{xx} - c v_x  = 0 \tag{2} 
\end{align}, one gets $B \neq 0$ at $\infty$.

Comment: There is no $B$ in the new system, so I'm not sure what you are talking about. You just find $v \sim e^{-ax}$ for some $a > 0$ while $u \sim e^{bx}$ for some $b > 0$. In the old system, yes, $B$ is zero as $x \to \infty$ and hence $u = v$, while $A$ is a constant $K_{2}$, so that $u, v \to K_{2}/2$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @mattos sorry I didn't make myself clear. If one takes $\lambda = 0$ and there is a continuous source of $B$ at $x =0$, $B$ is not $0$ at $\infty$. From what I can see,  with $\lambda > 0$, even with the continuous source, $B = 0$ at $\infty$.